# Is there any chance a project which compilation depends on the full profile that it will work in a machine with only the client profile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, msbuild, .net-client-profile

My project uses a given DLL. When I try to compile it with the .NET Framework 4.0 Client profile, it doesn't find the DLLs classes and the compilation fails.

After I switch to the full profile the compilation works.

Is there any chance that the resulting project will work on a machine with only .NET Framework Client Profile installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested and it worked. I think it's because I haven't used any method that exists only in the extended profile.